# How to change height of Slick carousel so the image would look good

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I have a simple slick carousel

```
<div class="your-class">
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="assets/img/train.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="assets/img/plane.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="assets/img/truck.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <img src="assets/img/ship.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

.slick-track {  
    display: flex !important; 
}  

.slick-slide {  
    height: inherit !important;     
    display: flex !important;   
    justify-content: center; 
} 

.slider {
    max-height: 400px;
}

.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

As you can see I want to change the size of slider to 400px but the image looks [flattened](https://prnt.sc/107h40r). If I remove slider height then the picture is too [big](https://prnt.sc/107h3im) with vertical scroll,I need to make img's height be approx 400px. Can you please help what I can do ?

Comment: This is quick fix `.slider img{ width: 100%;
    height: auto, object-fit: cover;}`.or resize your image according to need.

Comment: partially worked , but part of img has been cutted https://prnt.sc/107irrn

Comment: is there any way to do it better https://prnt.sc/107iv4e ?

Comment: resize image according to your need

Comment: Have you tried object-fit contain?